# Purpose of side holes on SuperDraco pods of DM-1 flight Dragon 2 capsule

Tags: spacex, dragon-v2, super-draco

I've watched the launch video for DM-1 today, and one thing caught my attention. On SuperDraco pods, below the plugged SuperDraco engine openings, there are two more plugged holes. I've marked them on a photo that I've found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpX-DM1.
[image]
Does someone know what is the purpose of these openings? I haven't seen them before on the Dragon 2 capsule used for pad abort test.

A close-up view from [here](https://www.teslarati.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/DM-1-Crew-Dragon-in-Florida-July-2018-SpaceX.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33863/crew-dragon-superdraco-engine-covers?

Comment: My guess would be something related to the spacecraft's reaction control system (RCS). The ones pointing downward appear to be the main ports for the SuperDraco's thrust. I'm not sure, I'm making educated guesses here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are the flaps that open and close to reveal the openings for the SuperDracos. The SuperDracos allow Dragon 2 to separate from the rocket during aborts. I think they swivel so the ones on the side go inward and the ones on top drop down to cover the holes made by the parts swiveling inwards.

https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-fires-redesigned-crew-dragon-superdraco-flaps/