Do rocket propellant tanks ever use internal structural elements to carry off-axis loads?
The interior of propellant tanks are usually portrayed as empty of structural elements. Here is the interior of a liquid hydrogen tank during assembly at the NASA rocket factory, with humans for scale:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_external_tank#/media/File:Space_Shuttle_external_tank_assembly_01.jpg
There are sometimes plumbing parts or anti-slosh devices, but not structural elements.
Here is a Saturn 1 kerosene tank with in-flight video of anti-slosh baffles in action:




An empty cylinder is structurally efficient, especially for a pressurized tank. But asymmetric loads, such as hard points for strap-on SRBs may benefit from internal bracing.
Do rocket propellant tanks ever use internal structural elements?

Highly related https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38103/6944

@OrganicMarble ... I'm interested in how off-axis loads, such as from SRBs, are carried. Question edited.

For shuttle and SLS, the SRB structures are between the tanks. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36349/6944

A hollow cylinder is not as structurally efficient as a sphere. The forces caused by internal pressure in circumference direction is two times of the force in axial direction.
